# Tool Resources - community wiki marked as "too broad"

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, quality-improvement

With the spirit of share resources, I made a question with community answers (I don't know how to make a community question, I didn't make the question to get points)

That question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975254/which-are-the-online-fiddlers-and-what-can-i-do-with-them

and the idea is about have a post with all fiddlers, and know some others.

A moderator mark the question as "too broad". I can understand why, but I think it brokes the spirit of the question, and I think the question is on the spirit of the site.

**So, my question is:**

**How can I edit this question in order to active it again?**

Comment: By the way, this question is not clear ?

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144359/why-is-the-definitive-c-book-list-question-allowed-but-other-book-recommend

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't.  What you want the question to be is inherently, at a fundamental level, too broad.  This site doesn't exist to support those types of questions.  To make the question narrow enough to be appropriate would be to fundamentally create an entirely different question with little resemblance to what it is now.

Comment: Thanks. It was analyzed as a feature in a previous context?

Comment: @Leandro FWIW ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)